# html5 add multiple canvas... use appendchild

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, appendchild

i want to add multiple canvas, but I am repeatedly fail .....
i want to add canvas image, it must be added linearly in one  tag
because i have to set fixed framework that is A4 size.
and i must use appendchild ..... 
here is my code...  please i need help.... please ......please....

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8" ></script>
var origin_canvas = document.getElementById('original_img');
var original_context = origin_canvas.getContext('2d');
var fileopen = document.getElementById('fileopen');
var add_img = document.getElementById('filter');

var div_filed = document.getElementById('canvas_pack');
var canvasElements = new Array(); 
var c_context = new Array();
// i want to add multiple canvas and canvas_filed

      for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
            canvasElements = document.createElement("canvas");
            div_Filed.appendChild(canvasElements);
            c_context.push(canvasElements.getContext('2d'));
        }
        
 add_img.onclick = function (event) {
  drawImage(origin_canvas);
 }

 fileopen.onchange = function (event) {
                console.log(this.value);
                /* Loading */
                var tgt = event.target || window.event.srcElement;
                var files = tgt.files;
                // FileReader support
                if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
                    var fr = new FileReader();
                    var image_load_tag = new Image();
                    image_load_tag.onload = function () {
                        drawImage(image_load_tag);
                    }
                    fr.onload = function () {
                        image_load_tag.src = fr.result;
                    }
                    fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                    delete image_load_tag;
                    delete fr;
                }
                else {}
            }

function drawImage(imageObj) {
            console.log('drawImage');
           origin_canvas.width = imageObj.width;
            origin_canvas.height = imageObj.height;
            original_context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
    <title>add multiple canvas </title>
</head>
    <style>
        .div-a{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;
        }
    </style>

<body>
 <div class = div-a id = "canvas_pack">
 <canvas id = "original_img></canvas>
 
 // this location is where the canvas has to be added ....

 </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since everyone is asking for help on this site, it is best to leave out "please help" from your question. If you can, write your question with these steps: what you want to do, what you tried, what doesn't work and how it doesn't work. Right now it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are script tags in your javascript code... I don't think that is allowed...